# In Drupal 7, What are some methods to prevent or detect botnets hammering your site?

Tags: advertising, captcha, 7

In drupal 7, what are some methods to stop botnets hammering your site? I have captcha protecting my registration page, but this doesn't stop them from bootstrapping my site when they land on the page. If enough load can be put on that page, it would lag my server. What are some tricks or modules that can prevent this scenario?